# Is the wing drag of induced drag + 2d drag at 0lift still accurate for cambered airfoils?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, viscosity, aircraft, lift

I have some work at uni that requires some aerofoil analysis to create a wing, but from the polar plots its clear that the cambered aeros have lower total 2d viscous drag (from xfoil) at the cl its operating at (0.45 around 1deg) is lower than at cl0. But surely this is not captured in the CD = Cd0+Cdi ?

Comment: Even without camber, the viscous drag coefficient varies with the lift coefficient. It's only a first approximation to use Cd0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually first run into this problem when we notice that the 2D data in the back of Theory of Wing Sections has a non-constant drag coefficient.

The drag variation looks parabolic, but because this is 2D flow, we know it is not induced drag.  As mentioned by Halsey, this effect exists for non-cambered airfoils.

This is a lift-dependent viscous drag.

The notion of a 3D aircraft drag polar of the form $C_D=C_{D,0}+C_{D,i}$ does not really leave room for this kind of thing.  This exact form is an artifact of applying a simplest level of theory.

When we add camber, we typically see a shift of the minimum drag point.  We often capture this in a linear term in the drag polar.

The induced drag for a wing with camber looks something like this...

$C_{D,i}=K\ \left(C_L-\Delta C_L\right)^2$

If we multiply out the RHS, we get

$K\left(\Delta C_L\right)^2 -2\ C_L\left(\Delta C_L\right)+K\ {C_L}^2$

The first term is a constant (in $C_L$), the second term is linear, and the third is the familiar quadratic term.

From this sort of reasoning, I prefer to use (for a 3D airplane) a form like...

$C_D=K_0+K_1C_L+K_2{C_L}^2$

I.e. a generic parabola.

In this form, some of the $K_0$ term is viscous in origin, but it also captures the constant term from the shift in the polar for a cambered configuration.

Likewise, the $K_2$ term captures both the primary induced drag effect, but it also gives us a place to track any viscous variation in drag that looks parabolic -- what we see in Theory of Wing Sections.

Of course, the real world is yet more complex.  Look at some 2D airfoil data for foils that are trying to achieve a region of laminar flow.  These will exhibit a 'laminar bucket' around the design lift coefficient.  This is a region of the polar with 'extra low' drag.

You can't capture a laminar bucket with a generic parabolic polar like the one above.  If your aircraft achieves substantial laminar flow, then you will likely need to use a tabulated (rather than fit and analytical) drag polar for your aircraft performance calculations.